# How can I show more results in a html php mysql table?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, mysqli

I'm trying to make an html table with the data in the database but when I write echo it just shows me a result. How can I echo all the elements?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM app_spot where company_id='$company_id'";

$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   $spot_id = $row["id"];
   $spot_name = $row["spot_name"];
   $store_location = $row["store_location"];
   $spot_budget = $row["spot_budget"];
   $spot_status = $row["spot_status"];

  }

  $spotcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);


} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: Is this the complete code?  There is no echo statement in the first branch of your if/else statement, so nothing will be output by this branch.  If there is some other code following this, then please edit your question to include it, but if not it sounds like you just need to add the appropriate `echo` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Echo the table rows in the `while` loop.

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Location</th><th>Budget</th><th>Status</th></tr>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $spot_id = $row["id"];
        $spot_name = $row["spot_name"];
        $store_location = $row["store_location"];
        $spot_budget = $row["spot_budget"];
        $spot_status = $row["spot_status"];
        echo "<tr><td>$spot_id</td><td>$spot_name</td><td>$store_location</td><td>$spot_budget</td><td>$spot_status</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```